# Advantages and disadvantages of including PDB files with your release application

Tags: .net, vb.net, debugging, pdb-files

I've got a VB.net application. Currently the release version of the application is produced without a PDB file. This gives me error logs lacking useful details such as line numbers.
I'm looking at including the PDB files with future builds but i'd like to know what the advantages and disadvantages of this are (performance wise, size wise, code security wise)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the PDB files? Unless you obfuscate the code, you already have nice stack traces with managed code (and I would assume PDB renders obfuscation useless anyway...). The only advantage you get are the "hidden" symbols such as locals and parameter names.

Comment: Drats.  I like this question, but it's already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307482/whats-the-risk-of-deploying-debug-symbols-pdb-file-in-a-production-environment

Comment: Parameter names and line numbers are very useful. Our app, is very large built by several different developers over several different versions of VB. Currently we have the name of the procedures in the stack, but it would be nice to have a little more data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you deploy your debug symbols for your application, it becomes really easy for someone to come along and reverse-engineer your work, which some people find undesirable.  Likewise, you have to deploy more files and your deployable project gets bigger.  The PDB files themselves don't cause the app to get any slower, as shipping a PDB doesn't always preclude forgoing optimizations (you just have to be careful -- the default "Debug" project settings tend to not optimize your outputs when they generate PDBs).

Answer (score 13):

I know I'm going to get beat up for this but...

I agree with Dave Markle, but I'd like to add that an advantage of publishing the PDB files is, as you said, VERY nice for debugging.

That said, I don't sell software, and the code I write is all for internal use in our company. In this context, I don't see an issue with putting debug code into production, along with the PDB files.  I've never seen a performance hit, and in all honesty, our users rarely give us the right information if they encounter unhandled exceptions.  Of course, we try to handle exceptions correctly, but as you know, errors will happen.  Our strategy is to add a global exception handler to ALL projects, and log those events tot he database.  These errors contain the line numbers because we do include the debug files, and as a result, we are able to quickly identify and react to bad code, fix it, and get more bug-free applications.  To me (and to our users) this is a HUGE benefit that I wouldn't want to do without.

So if you're in a similar situation, I say forget the official stance (in this one case) and go ahead and publish the pdb files with ONE important caveat.

Be darn sure that any web application you deploy with the PDB files, be completely sure that ALL exceptions are handled properly, and you're not inadvertently exposing lines of code in a standard Asp.NET error page.

Answer (score 2):

Create pdbs for your release build, but do not ship them. Keep the pdbs somewhere safe with the matching build and source code. If you get a live crash, or similar, you can use the pdbs to do post-mortem debugging using the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551063(VS.85).aspx), or Visual Studio.

Comment: We try and keep all exceptions handled. So we don't do post mortem debugging. On handled exceptions we log the stack trace to the database

Comment: Post mortem debugging is also useful when you do not get any exceptions thrown, e.g., if your application hangs. You can capture a mini-dump of the hung process, and then debug it remotely using the pdbs and source code.

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to also have debug information built for the Release version - it helps with catching bugs. It doesn't make the program run slower. But you shouldn't ship the PDB file with your application, if you don't want others to be able to reverse-engineer it more easily. Only give it to testers.

Comment: The application is an intenal application. It's only going to be used within our company. User restrictions prevent users from being able to reverse engineerour code