# Release Build contains extra files, do I need these?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I built my program with Visual Studio 2012 Express, bin/release/ contains some other files as well as the exe. Do I need to distribute these files?

- myApp.exe.config
- myApp.pdb
- myApp.vshost.exe
- myApp.vshost.exe.config
- myApp.vshost.exe.manifest

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do (probably) need

- myApp.exe.config

That contains configuration settings for your executable.

You don't need the others.

- myApp.pdb

Contains debug symbols

- myApp.vshost.*

Used by Visual Studio when debugging (*vshost* means Visual Studio Host).

Comment: Well, the ".config" may or may not be used by him.  We can't really know if he's storing configuration data in it.  I know in my apps it's pretty rarely used, although it's the only one there that (beyond the exe itself) has the potential to belong in a production environment.

Comment: @Servy: Thus "probably".  Many apps have at least a setting or a connection string, though surely not all.

Answer (score 8):

It depends.
The other answers are correct in saying that myApp.exe and myApp.exe.config are the essential choices.

You may also want to ship the PDB file. If you do, you have more options for debug purposes (for example - it's possible to log the line number in code where an exception was thrown).

There's probably not any use cases where you want to ship the vshost files.

HOWEVER: Shipping anything apart from just the exe and the config can make your software easier to reverse engineer; and increases your package size.

**I think in most cases the answer will be, only ship myApp.exe and myApp.exe.config** for those reasons.

Have a look at these previous questions for further information:

[Advantages and Disadvantages of Including PDB Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825813/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-including-pdb-files-with-your-release-applicatio)

[Release Version Has Still PDB File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371032/c-sharp-release-version-has-still-pdb-file)

[How To Turn Off PDB Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453841/how-to-turn-off-pdb-generation-and-vshost-for-all-release-builds)

[What Is The Purpose Of vshost exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-vshost-exe-file)

Comment: You say "the other files", but I guess you only mean the PDB?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, I think that's probably the case

Answer (score 2):

myApp.exe > yes

myApp.exe.config > yes

others > no

Answer (score 1):

To get the best performance of your application when deploying your code to your client, you can get rid of the:

myApp.pdb

This is a good article on what developers need to know about pdb files:
https://www.wintellect.com/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know/

pdb files are for debugging purposes