# What is the use of removing pdb files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, compilation, pdb-files

I read somewhere that removing `.pdb` file cause increase in performance of the program. What are the cons and pros of removing these files?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381537/deploying-pdb-files-in-iis-any-benefit

Comment: Short answer: Performance is not affected. Long answer: [Do PDB Files Affect Performance?](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/do-pdb-files-affect-performance)

Comment: [Advantages and disadvantages of including PDB files with your release application][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825813/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-including-pdb-files-with-your-release-applicatio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDB stands for Program Database, a proprietary file format (developed by Microsoft) for storing debugging information about a program (or, commonly, program modules such as a DLL or EXE)
Without the PDB files, it would be impossible to debug a release build by anything other than address-level debugging.

So, in brief, it's not required to run the application. It's just required once you fire up a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

PDBs contain additional symbolic information about your code that you may want to keep private and away from the eyes of enterprising hackers.