# Visual Studio 2013 Website Publish Not Copying .pdb files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, release, pdb-files

I have checked the answer for VS 2012, it did not work. I do not precompile, I have **"Debug Info"** set to *"full"*, **"Items to deploy"** set to *"Only files needed to run this application"* and **"Exclude generated debug symbols"** not marked.

I have tested with *"All files in this project"*, and I have tried to edit the pubxml file. Besides not working I cannot find the file schema documentation.

Please help.

Comment: Is there a reason for you to copy the debug store files (*.pdb files)? Usually when you publish a website you're publishing to a live environment.

Comment: The main reason is to allow remote debugging, our relation with our consumers is pretty close so we do not care much for source protection.

Comment: Another reason might be to have line numbers in call stack when an exception happens. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1307482/108374

Comment: Actually, PDBs only include source file names/line numbers, and local variable names ... the actual information is already in your shipped DLL. Try generating a complete project from a DLL with dotPeek, for example.

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of tests, I noticed that **"Exclude generated debug symbols"** flickered as marked during the publish processing. My error was that I was editing the *Active* configuration -- **which was *Debug*** -- and not the *Release* configuration used in my publish process.

Please verify the Configuration combo on the project properties page, this was bizarre until I noticed that.

Comment: I excluded the bin folder from the solution.  Then, I was able to publish.

Answer (score 2):

There´s an option in the `Advanced Precompile Settings` dialog (which is off by default); you find this dialog via the `Settings` tab of the `Publish Web` wizard... watch out for the (unoticable) `Configure`-link in the `File Publish Options`-drop-down...

[image]

Comment: I was not precompiling, I did it and interestingly got a App_Code.pdb and App_global.asax.pdb but all my other pdbs are not copied.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched for this and tried every trick posted and nothing worked.

**The only thing that worked for me** was to take a copy of the bin folder and then delete all files from the bin folder and rebuild. 
When publishing I got a new error of a missing .dll which I had in the backup folder. When I copied it to the bin folder I was finally able to publish.