# Pros and Cons of supplying pdb file to customer

Tags: pdb-files

My company publishes a proprietary software component.  We have a customer that is having an issue (may be with our product or their application, they don't know) and they've asked us to supply the .pdb file so they can debug.  We're hesitant because we want to protect our intellectual property to the highest degree.  So, is our fear unfounded?  Or is there risk to supplying the file?

Comment: I don't think there is, since Microsoft supplies theirs?

Comment: Also looks like this has been asked and answered? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307482/whats-the-risk-of-deploying-debug-symbols-pdb-file-in-a-production-environmen